# Foreign Key Leftover From Table Drop

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I'm having a situation where someone dropped a table, but the foreign keys are still left in the sys.foreign_keys. Is there a way to drop a foreign key that no longer has a table, or should I try just deleting the row from sys.foreign_keys?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying system tables is bad idea. **Don't do that**. In fact, SQL Server won't allow you to do that easily.

You should try first with this commands:

```
DBCC CHECKDB
DBCC CHECKCATALOG
DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS (constraint_name)
```

(if you omit database name, the current database is used).
If you really have an foreign key without the table, dbcc should detect it. Read the result from dbcc output and pay attention on error messages.

Also, try with:

```
SELECT
  name,
  is_disabled,
  is_not_trusted
FROM   sys.foreign_keys
WHERE  is_disabled = 1
    OR is_not_trusted = 1
```

and see if you can get more info from SQL Server.